# woocommerce transactional emails: using g suite or mailgun? recommendations and experiences

Tags: woocommerce, smtp

I want to use SMTP for transactional emails in woocommerce.

As I understand the sending limits for G Suite are: 130 mails per day (SMTP)

Is this right?
I used this reference link:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay

(Review sending limits for the SMTP relay service)

or is the 2000/day column relevant? https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

I hope this isn't too off-topic for stackoverflow... 
mailgun wants me to set up a subdomain like mail.domein.com and I'm afraid of technical difficulties because I've already set up the MX record for g suite.
Does anyone have experience with using these SMTP solutions?

Answer (score 2):

To give a strictly Mailgun-related answer, as I am also confused by GSuite's wording on daily-sending limits:

For simply sending transaction emails (not receiving), you can use Mailgun on a subdomain.

1. You have GSuite MX records already in place
2. Sign up for a Mailgun account and [Add a Domain](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203637190-How-Do-I-Add-a-Domain-) (a subdomain)
3. Configure your domain's DNS with the TXT, MX, and CNAME records provided by Mailgun
4. Use Mailgun's DNS verification tool to ensure your records have been added correctly
5. Once you configure WordPress/WooCommerce's SMTP settings to use your Mailgun account, you should be able to test sending transaction emails and also send/receive separately on your GSuite-related root domain.

To speak from experience, I use GSuite Business for my incoming/outgoing business emails with MX records on my root domain (mydomain.com). For sending WooCommerce transaction emails, I use Mailgun on a subdomain (mg.mydomain.com).

Comment: thanks for you answer:) so I tried to set up mailgun but I've already set up MX records for g suite. what did you do to solve this conflict?

Comment: @mika2019 You can set up a subdomain for Mailgun to use. For example, **mg**.yourdomain.com. GSuite will be using **yourdomain.com**, but Mailgun will be using **mg**.yourdomain.com. With this in mind, take another look through the steps I've posted above. In short, you'll have two sets of MX records on your domain that will not conflict with each other. GSuite will be on **yourdomain.com**, and Mailgun will be on **subdomain.yourdomain.com**. In my examples, when I write mg.mydomain.com, the "mg" is the subdomain part. Good luck, and feel free to let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: ah ok, so I have to go to siteground godaddy whatever and create a subdomain mail.yourdomain.com on the server? I haven't created a subdomain but entered the TXT for mail.youdomain.com anyway and weirdly enough mailgun verified the subdomain without there being the subdomain "physically" on the server... when a customer replies to the transactional emails, are these mail going to mailgun or gsuite? Do I have to set up something at mailgung, that is forwarding the replies to my gsuite account?  I'm sorry, I feel stupid, but this email thing is confusing me;)

Comment: Adding the TXT, MX, and CNAME records provided by Mailgun is all you need to do for setting up a Mailgun subdomain (e.g., no Apache configuration required). Regarding customers replying to transaction emails sent by Mailgun, you can route replies to the transaction emails so that they're sent to another email address (e.g., your GSuite/primary address) and respond from there (see Routes section of your account). Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: For example, my transaction emails are sent by Mailgun from orders@mg.mydomain.com. If a customer responds to that email, it will be routed by Mailgun to orders@mydomain.com (primary GSuite email). When I respond back to the customer, we both have the whole email thread, but we're now communicating on my primary domain through GSuite. When testing this, be sure to test from an outside email address (just like a customer would be). In other words, make a test order from a test customer @someotherdomain.com, and reply to your Mailgun transaction email. Everything should work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the google support answer for anyone who also wants to know more about the confusing sending limits:

From your message I understand that you need further information regarding the SMTP relay send limits related to an Basic account.

In particular, the SMTP relay send limits are related to the number of licenses in use (users), not taking in consideration the kind of subscription chosen (invoiced or free). This means the limits remain the same for Basic, Business, Enterprise or Edu/Non-profit editions.  These limits do not inhibit normal email use, but are designed to help identify any misuse of Gmail.

In any case, since these limits can’t be raised on a per request basis you could, as a workaround, create users free of charge in order to raise your own limits accordingly to your needs.

For example, if there are 50 users created in the Admin Console, the SMTP relay send limit will be: 50 x 130 = 6500 recipient for 24 hours. The advantage of using an API, it the ability to spread the mail load within the 24 hours time window or calibrate the amount of messages sent/synced/fetched deciding whenever the API calls has to be made.